# Reroute NGINX path to another path (without http redirect)

Tags: nginx

I want to be able to go to these URLs below

http://assets.mydomain.com/static/style.css

http://assets.mydomain.com/v999/static/style.css

And in NGINX, either urls above should instead point to

/var/www/vhosts/mysite/public/static/style.css

How can I do this? I had thought it was simply a case of doing alias but it doesn't seem to be the case

ie.

```
location ~* ^/v(.*)/ {
    alias $rootPath;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Below is my full nginx config.

```
server {
    set $rootPath /var/www/vhosts/mysite/public;

    listen 80;

    server_name assets.mydomain.com;

    root $rootPath;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_assets.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_assets.log debug;

    index index.html index.htm;

    # Any files matching these extensions are cached for a long time
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    # Don't throw any errors for missing favicons and don't display them in the logs
    location /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
    }

    # Deny these extensions
    location ~* \.(txt|php|less)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^/v(.*)/ {
        alias $rootPath;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is only:

```
server {
    set $rootPath /var/www/vhosts/mysite/public;

    listen 80;

    server_name assets.mydomain.com;

    root $rootPath;

    location /v999/ {
        root $rootPath;
    }
    ...

}
```

See [location on nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)